# How to remove 'experience' on Careers 2.0?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Since the launch of Careers 2.0, I've been working on actually completing my profile. I have one thing listed thus far under experience, which was a contract position and for various reasons I'd like to remove it.

I click `[edit] -> [remove]` - yet it persists. Is this a bug? It is the only 'experience' I have listed, my profile is not yet published / filed.

I don't want to add to 'experience' without the assurance of editorial control (on my part), in the past I've worked under quite strict non-disclosure agreements and people are sometimes fickle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We think we've found the problem -- try again now.

Comment: Just for fun, what situations caused the problem to happen?

Comment: @jjnguy if you had an old, unsaved draft from Careers 1.0

Comment: so my hypothesis was wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: It's working now :)